# C++ wchar_t error undefined

Tags: c++, wchar-t

I'm new to c++.

I know wchar_t is wide character.

What is wrong in the following code ?? Did i not include the appropriate library ??

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
wchar_t *s=L"Hello, World";
cout<<s;
getch();
}
```

Comment: i just wrote <iostream> it says, "Unable to open include file IOSTREAM".

Comment: If your compiler doesn't have `<iostream>` then it does not implement the C++ standard and in all likelihood has not been updated since some previous millennium. You should not be using it, and especially you should not be learning with it. (And if you're using a book that mentions iostream.h you should probably throw it out.) There are many good, free options available today including VS2012 express, and gcc 4.7.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, stop using Borland Turbo C - it was old when I first pickd up version 3.1 nearly 20 years ago. Turbo C from that era doesn't have a iostream (no extension) file because it was released at a time before the stl was. Prior to that time, the functions were indeed found in iostream.h

As such, I'd expect that it also didn't define wchar_t - I don't even remember if multibyte stuff was around then, unicode certainly wasn't a consideration..

For what it's worth, I've still got a copy of Turbo C on 5 1/4" floppy discs - yes! The floppy floppies... Get a compiler from this century!

Get Code::Blocks with MinGW (~70MB download), or Visual Studio Express (couple hundred), hell - even DevCpp is less archaic than Turbo C.

(Oh, and you've indicated to me that it's overwhelmingly likely your compiler of choice through the inclusion of conio.h)

Comment: Um, the STL is HP's Standard Template Library. It has nothing to do with iostreams. The change in name came with the first C++ Standard in 1998.

Answer (score 2):

A number of problems here, though all pretty minor:

```
#include<iostream.h>
```

This  should be `#include <iostream>` The standard C++ headers don't have a `.h` on the end.

```
void main()
```

`main` should return an `int`, not `void`.

```
wchar_t *s=L"Hello, World";
cout<<s;
```

To write a wide string, you want to use `wcout`, which is in the `std` namespace, so this should look like:

```
std::wcout << s;
```

Note that `getch`:

```
getch();
```

... is common, but technically not standard, so you can't use it in truly portable code. If you only care about Windows though, that may not be a concern for you.

Comment: List your compiler and version.  Does the following program compile: `#include <iostream>` then press enter then type `int main() {}`?

Comment: no #include <iostream> alone shows the same error.

compiler version: 3.0

Comment: @Ajay: If your compiler is old enough that it doesn't include an `<iostream>`, chances are *pretty* good that it also lacks any support for wide characters at all.